# Java arrays in C code

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays

I'm learning about Java arrays and coming from a C/C++ background I was trying to wrap my head around the whole concept of arrays in Java. 
Since everything in Java is  a pointer, I understand that even arrays are pointers to objects (array objects in this case), and that these array object contain either primitive type values (int[] ia) or pointers to objects (String[] sa), since we can't manipulate objects like in C++, but only references to objects on the heap.
So is it correct to represent a 2-dimensional Java array in C code like this:

```
TYPE *(*(*aptr)[M])[N];

(*aptr)          has type: TYPE *(*[M])[N] and is converted to: TYPE *(**)[N]
(*aptr)[m]       has type: TYPE *(*)[N]      
*(aptr)[m]       has type: TYPE *[N]       and is converted to: TYPE **
(*(*aptr)[m])[n] has type: TYPE *

so

TYPE obj = *(*(*aptr)[m])[n]) has type TYPE
```

did I get it right?

Comment: to whom flagged the question: I'm asking if my reasoning is correct, and if not I kindly ask to provide the correct answer.

Comment: If you are dealing with Java, you better forget about pointers. At first at least.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, but since Java reference are pointers at heart I find very enlightening to try to represent a Java array in C code (just for learning purposes)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What is that code(is it even code) ?

Comment: @FrankUnderwood indeed it is not code (we can try to submiti it to a compiler :D )
I'm asking if it is correct to represent a Java array in C code like I did in the question

Comment: It's not really a question though its more of a code review no?

Comment: This is more of a code review than actual question

Comment: @dave well, I'm asking if it's right since I can't find an answer anywhere

Comment: @BudsNanKis a code review can become a question if you append a question mark?

Comment: @BudsNanKis A code review would at least have some code...

Comment: @tofro it's not executable code, but it's C. first line is a declaration if you insert a valid built-in or object type. Following lines are consideration on what type each valid C expression would have.

Comment: I wonder if we're going to argue on the question format or someone is going to help me out on this

Comment: "Since everything in Java is a pointer"  No, everything in Java is a reference to an object, which is probably not an array of primitive data types.

Comment: I am pretty sure your comparison is not leading you anywhere (or if there is something useful to learn from it). Java runs on a virtual machine whose bytecode doesn't even know pointers. That means java bytecode is a machine language for a "CPU" that cannot handle addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two points. A Java array knows about its type and its length, so its C equivalent would be a struct. A rough analogy for a Java int[] array would be (this explanation does not mean that any existing JVM uses this structure, it's just meant as a C language analogy for the Java array):

```
struct int_array {
    TYPE *type;  // This points to a description that we are an int[] array
    int length;
    int *data;   // Allocated with malloc(length*sizeof(int))
};
```

And Java `a[i]` then translates to C `a->data[i]` plus throwing of an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `i` lies outside of `0...length-1`.

A 2-dimensional array is just an array of arrays, e.g. an int[][] might look like:

```
struct two_dim_int_array {
    TYPE *type;  // This points to a description that we are an int[][] array
    int length;
    struct int_array *data;   // Allocated with malloc(length*sizeof(struct int_array))
};
```

So, `b[i][j]` translates to `b->data[i].data[j]` with the necessary range and null checks.

Comment: FYI, in C++ there is `std::vector`, which is equivalent.

Comment: My C/C++ knowledge is quite rusty (stopped more or less with ANSI C), as I switched to Java when it became popular in the late 90s. But anyway, I think for such low-level explanations, plain old C gives the clearest view.